# Is there another way to Jamaica without transiting through US. Am from Uganda

Tags: transit-visas

Going through US is a long shot.how about through UK or any other country

Comment: You can get direct flights to Jamaica from Western Europe.

Comment: Pretty certain you will need a visa to transit the UK, you can check if you qualify for transit without visa here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Answer (score 5):

A quick check of Wikipedia [indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Manley_International_Airport) that there are flights to Kingston, Jamaica from London (UK) and Toronto (Canada). It also shows regular flights to Panama City, which has flights from other European countries such as France, Spain, and the Netherlands. There is also a flight from Beijing to Panama City, so if you can get to China you can avoid transiting Europe too.

Now, before you book travel, it is probably worth asking *why* you want to avoid the US. Were you rejected for a visa? Have you been specifically banned from entering the US? Are you more vaguely concerned with some things you have heard about the US or how hard it supposedly is to get a visa?

Comment: There are also flights from Montego Bay to Montreal, Brussels & Frankfurt.  (Montego Bay has more connections than Kingston does, probably because of the tourist trade;  for the same reason, the connections are usually just a few times a week rather than daily.)

Comment: Getting a visa, even a transit visa, is a big issue for someone from a Third-World country like Uganda.  You have to be interviewed at the US consulate and pay $160.  However, the cheapest and fastest flight is DXB/JFK.